# How should I model processes in RxJava?

Tags: java, design-patterns, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

Suppose I have some process, such as downloading a file or running a big computation.

The events it fires might look like this:

```
{ progress: "0%" }
{ progress: "23%" }
{ progress: "78%" }
{ progress: "100%" }
{ content: "Hello. world. " }
```

Or perhaps:

```
{ progress: "0%" }
{ progress: "23%" }
{ error: "Access denied. " }
```

In each case, we have `n` status-updates (`T`) followed by either a result (`S`) or an error (`Throwable`):

```
T* ( S | Throwable )
```

A process is a mix of `Observable<T>` and `Single<S>`.

There are a few ways to model a process using the Rx primitives:

- A pair of `Observable<T>` and `Single<S>`
- An `Observable<Either<T, S>>`
- An `Observable<Object>` with `instanceof` calls for casting
- A new primitive `Process<T, S>` with `toObservable` and `toSingle` methods
- etc...

How has this been successfully modelled in the past?

Which approaches are best and when should they be used?

Answer (score 1):

Let us rule out the `Object` plus `instanceof` right away. This is the certain road to madness.

It will depend on how you are going to use the `T` and `S` results. I believe that `T` should be a container of `S`.

```
class T<S> {
  public boolean isSuccess() { ... }
  public boolean isStatus() { ... }
  public Status getStatus() { ... }
  public S getResult() { ... }
}
```

The initial stream of emitted values have simply the status values (progress amounts), while the last item in the stream carries the `S` value.

If you need `S` to be a `Single`, then

```
observable
  .filter( t -> t.isSuccess() )
  .last()
  .map( t -> t.getResult() )
  .toSingle()
```

will be adequate. If you need the status reports to appear elsewhere then use

```
observable.filter( t-> t.isStatus() )
```

This gives you your

Comment: @sdgfsdh Both cases that you mention work; what's the objection?

Comment: Ah I misread sorry. This solution is the same as the either solution above. This does not guarantee that only the last value is a success. Might be a reasonable compromise though.

Comment: An error is always a terminal event in Rx; you can always do an `.onErrorResumeNext(t -> Observable.just(new ErrorInstance(t)))` if you absolutely need the error in the normal stream.